# Correct usage of the onEnrollmentLink() function?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'd like to capture when a user clicks on an enrolment link, do some stuff, then let the normal enrolment flow continue. But when I use the `onEnrollmentLink()` function it stalls the user's journey.

I've tried:

```js
Accounts.onEnrollmentLink(function(token, done){
    Session.set('mySessionVar', 'something');
    done();
});
```

I've tried returning the done callback `return done();` or `return done`; but this also doesn't work.

The docs state:

> **done:** A function to call when the enrollment UI flow is complete. The normal login process is suspended until this function is called, so that user A can be enrolled even if user B was logged in.

Sadly, there's no example in the docs and the text is not clear. Does anyone know the correct way to implement this function?

Comment: "_user B remains logged in, which is not correct._" So you want to log out all other users when a new user enrolls?

Comment: Yes. This is actually how enrolment works normally and I simply want the normal enrolment flow to continue but when I use this function the flow is stalled and I cannot restart it.

Comment: Can't you just call `Meteor.logout()` at the beginning of your callback then?

Comment: That would log out the current user, sure, but the problem here is the flow gets suspended so the new user is not being logged in. I'll update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Hi did you ever get this working? It seems like my Accounts.onEnrollmentLink doesn't even get called when a user hits the link.

Comment: @AdamMoisa Are/were you setting a custom link via `Accounts.urls.enrollAccount`?

Answer (score 0):

For any that arrived here because they were a little confused with documentation.

```
Accounts.onEnrollmentLink(...)
```

Is intended to work with flowRouter, as it's the official Meteor router, (not the only one, but official).

In order to complete the enrollment process altogether, just design what you want in particular. 
For example, the common scenario is one where the on-boarding is done by **Invite** and then **User access**, where the user will input his desired password:

1. Create a user:

   ```
   const user = { username, email, password };
   ```

   and set it in

   ```
   let userId = Accounts.createUser({ username, email, password });
   ```

   followed by

   ```
   Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId);
   ```
2. User clicks the link and navigates to your site, where in front end you can use a form to ask for a password. **If you're not using Flow router, but another front end such as Angular, React or VueJS**, you won't ask `Accounts.onEnrollmentLink(...)` ever. You'll do the next step.
3. Find user by token, which should have been set in URL, probably use a Method instead of Publish

   ```
   function findByEnrollToken(token: string) {
       return Meteor.users.findOne({ "services.password.reset.token": token });
   }
   ```
4. Finally, set new user password using `Accounts.resetPassword(token, newPassword, [callback])` where the password was set on front end.

That's it, you can additionally use `Accounts.verifyEmail(token, [callback])` along with `Accounts.resetPassword()` in the same submit function.

Comment: Why do we need to do step 3? if we get the user based on the token what will that be used for? I dont see it being used in step 4 or the text after that.

Comment: You don't need to do it, it's showcased as an alternative example of  onEnrollmentLink method's purpose.

You'd use step 3 if you want some logic on Back End (e.g.: send email, etc.).
Step 4 is Front end exposed.

The key usage here, is the token usage.